# Convert NT file time to Win32 time

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to convert the LARGE_INTEGER CreationTime member in [this structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the FILETIME ftCreationTime member in [this structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The times are in different formats so simply casting it does not work, is there any documentation on what format NT API uses for file time and how I could convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same representation, just different structures. You can either memcpy it across or manual assignment:

```
FILETIME ft;
LARGE_INTEGER creationTime;

memcpy(&ft, &creationTime, sizeof(ft));
```

or

```
FILETIME ft;
LARGE_INTEGER creationTime;

ft.dwLowDateTime = creationTime.LowPart;
ft.dwHighDateTime = creationTime.HighPart;
```

Comment: Assigning the dwLow/HighDateTime members is the preferred method, as it is more portable across different architectures.